# PHP photo upload preview does not work with mobile camera photo

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload

I have a responsive web app on which the user can upload photos.  Works great on the desktop and even works on the mobile phone as long as you select an existing file and don't try to take a photo to upload.

When you click the upload element on your phone, the OS gives you the choice between choosing from the stored files or using the camera.  If if you use the camera, the upload works, but the preview does not EXCEPT if I insert an alert somewhere in the following javascript.  (This code is triggered on change of the file input)

```
var photoFileSelected = function(event) {
  var input = event.target;

  //************************************************************************//
  //*** Initialize previewPopup
  //************************************************************************//

  var previewPopup = $('#uploadprompt').mobiscroll4().popup({
    display: 'top',
    responsive: {small: {display: 'center'}},
    closeOnOverlayTap: false,
    buttons: [{
        text: 'Save',
        cssClass: 'mbsc-fr-btn uploadprompt-okbutton mbsc-disabled',
        handler: function(event,inst){startUploadingPhoto();}
      },'cancel'],
    }).mobiscroll4('getInst');

  //************************************************************************//
  //*** Validate selected file
  //************************************************************************//

  // get selected file element
  var oFile = document.getElementById('image_file_photo').files[0];
  var valid = true;

  // filter for image files
  var rFilter = /^(image\/bmp|image\/gif|image\/jpeg|image\/png|image\/tiff)$/i;
  if (! rFilter.test(oFile.type)) {
    popup("Error","Invalid file type selected.  Must be an image file")
    valid = false;
  }

  // little test for filesize
  if (oFile.size > iMaxFilesize) {
    popup("Error","Selected file is too large.  Max size is 10 MB.")
    valid = false;
  }

  if(valid){

    //************************************************************************//
    //*** Load image preview
    //************************************************************************//

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      $('.uploadprompt-okbutton').removeClass('mbsc-disabled');
      var dataURL = reader.result;
      $('#preview-photo').attr("src",dataURL);
    };

    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    previewPopup.show();
  }

};
```

I can alert oFile.size for example and it alerts a value, and when I dismiss the popup the preview is loaded and all is good.  If I comment out the alert the preview is not loaded at all, most of the time.  Sometimes I can get it to load but I can't seem to find the pattern.  It seems random.  I've gotten it to load maybe 5% of the time but the vast majority of the time the preview will not show, but I know the file upload is working because as I said I can alert the file size and even the dataURL and it looks normal.

I also tried using setTimeout() to see if it was a timing issue but that didn't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure on the best suggestion for the specific issue with your code, at this point, aside from asking whether the browser is actually reporting any javascript errors?  To be honest, I've not used the FileReader() when I want to do this sort of previewing of a local image before a file is uploaded - using your code as an example, I would just set the "src" of the preview image as "input.files[0]", and the browser should take care of rendering the image.  Are you using FileReader() for any subsequent purpose?  If it's simply for the image preview, I think you can do without it

Comment: There are no JavaScript errors unfortunately as that would make it easy to track down.  I also tried your suggestion of assigning input.files[0] right into the src of the preview image but if I do it that way I never get a preview at all.

Comment: Actually, I went back and checked some of my previous code, and I actually wrap the (in your case) "input.files[0]" value in URL.createObjectURL().  You could give that a try.  Otherwise can you add some more of your HTML so that we can see the actual file input element and the image element that's supposed to be displaying the preview?

Comment: Thanks for your comments but it looks like I've got it figured out.  I'll post an answer to explain, in case it helps somebody else.

Comment: Good news!  And yes, definitely post the answer - that is the point, after all - to help others as well as yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had to enable USB debugging on my Android to find the answer to this.  The problem was that my preview img was inside a popup window, and inside this popup window I do not have access to document.getElementById("preview-photo") nor $('#preview-photo'), though I'm not sure why, so my preview image tag was null.

I had to change it to get a handle to the tag by classname.

```
var previewimage = this.getElementsByClassName('preview-photo')[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.readAsDataURL(oFile); 

reader.onloadend = function(){ 
  previewimage.src = reader.result;
}
```

I suppose $('.preview-photo').attr('src',reader.result) would've worked as well.

I don't know why the file selector on the mobile phone worked previously, cause based on this that also should not have worked, and I also don't know why inserting an alert made it work, but whatevs.  It's working now.

Pro tip of the day: use the USB debugger in Android.